# Android HTTP authentication on Lotus Domino server

Tags: android, lotus-domino

I am developing an android application capable of read data from a Lotus Domino database.
I started to create a page to test the HTTP authentication and I encountered many difficulties. This is my code snippet:

```
    public void GoAuth(View v){
    final String httpsURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/names.nsf/mypage?openpage";
    final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(httpsURL);

    String userName = "demo";
    String password = "demo";

    try {
        //authentication block:
        final List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", userName));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
        final UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httppost.setEntity(p_entity);

        //sending the request and retrieving the response:
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            //handling the response 
            final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(responseEntity.getContent());
            TextView res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
            res.setText("Server response: "+inputSource.toString());
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

The server response is:
    org.xml.sax
    InputSource@40575700

Trying the same in a browser I see the login page and after then the content of "mypage".
I am a bit confused about the right approach and mechanism I have to follow on android.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting the response to be? HTML? Creating an `InputSource` achieves *nothing* except preparing the content received from the server to be parsed by for instance a SAX parser. Do you just want to dump the servers response - in that case you should just use [EntityUtils#toString(responseEntity)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html).

Comment: Are you seeing a login page, or are you seeing a login dialog?  If you are seeing a full page, then the Domino server is configured to use session (cookie-based) authentication instead of basic authentication.

Comment: @rhsatrhs I see the login page, the server is configured to use session authentication

Comment: @Jens I am expecting to have HTML as the response; I tried your suggestion replacing the line res.setText("Server response: "+EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));  but receive a IllegalStateException, "Content has been consumed"

Comment: that's thrown if you've already attempted to read the content you've got in your entity.. Only call response.getEntity() *once*, and only attempt to read the InputStream it returns *once*.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I can see the server response that is the html of the login page... so my authentication function failed

Answer (score 2):

As Richard mentioned in the comments, you are probably seeing the "[session based authentication](http://www.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/03a88698ea068ece8525706f0065d96f?OpenDocument) form" which is rather cumbersome to work around with any kind of code.

In order, to get "HTTP Basic Authentication", which probably any language can handle easily (the browser based username/password prompt), you can/should implement a [Override Session Authentication Rule](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/07282008031247PMKMKQJ3.htm) on the server side.

See also [Domino 7.0.2 allows for overriding of session-based authentication](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21250004)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the central part of some code I have been using in a couple of Android apps that synchronize with Lotus Domino:

```
    private boolean authenticateWithDomino() throws Exception {

    String fullLoginUrl = "";

    if (useSSL) {
        fullLoginUrl = "https://" + hostName + ":" + httpPort + "/names.nsf?Login";
    } else {
        fullLoginUrl = "http://" + hostName + ":" + httpPort + "/names.nsf?Login";
    }

    DominoHttpRequest dominoRequest = DominoHttpClient.getInstance()
            .createRequest();
    dominoRequest.setUrl(fullLoginUrl);
    dominoRequest.setMethod("POST");
    dominoRequest.addParam("username", notesName);
    dominoRequest.addParam("password", notesPassword);
    dominoRequest.addParam("redirectto", "/icons/ecblank.gif");
    dominoRequest.execute();
    }
```

Some notes on useage:

- This works with Session based authentication, but not with Basic authentication.
- names.nsf might not be the file name of the server directory, but it usually is.
- Note the the port number. Usually it is 80 for regular http and 443 for https, but they are configurable on the Domino server.

Added later... Here is a link to a Java Class that does "replication" with Domino: [DiscussionReplicator.java](http://github.com/OpenNTF/DomDIsc/blob/master/DomDisc/src/org/openntf/domdisc/general/DiscussionReplicator.java). Look for a method called **getAuthenticationToken** which returns either a "DominoAuthSessID=xyz" or a "LtpaToken=abc"

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens, I don't understand the two classes DominoHttpRequest and DominoHttpClient. Any details on these? (Are they a custom classes? Shall I use the standard org.apache.http.HttpRequest?)

Comment: Yes, DominoHttpRequest and DominoHttpClient are my custom classes. I can't make all the code available on the internet. I am using org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.

Comment: Great! Thanks to yours suggestions I made it! I used http basic authentication and I was thinking about security; using **https** is enough to be "quiet" against traffic sniffer?

Comment: HTTPS protects the password from traffic sniffers, yes. A determined hacker with the proper resources would probably be able to get at the password and username. Good resource here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190771/how-secure-is-sending-sensitive-data-over-https

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the code above will work for posting the credentials to the Domino Server but you will need to handle any issues with a login failure - whether its due to authentication or authorization.

BTW Bypassing the Domino Login form is often done client side as demonstrated here - http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20081008  and has the same issues.

On my blog I talk about creating a custom Login Form on the server within the Domino Configuration Database - this is a standard and inbuilt configuration database.  This custom login form is not designed to be directly opened, instead its designed for third party systems to authenticate against, it will then return JSON data with any authentication / authorization issues.

You could use the same approach and convert to XML if you would find it easier to consume within the Java code.

The link to the article is here: http://www.markbarton.com/?p=314

A link to information about the Domino Configuration DB (domconfig.nsf) is here 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_CREATING_THE_DOMINO_CONFIGURATION_DATABASE.html