# How it HTTPS secure? Can't anyone decrypt the responses?

Tags: security, https, cryptography

I understand the concept of public-key cryptography, and HTTPS makes perfect sense to me in terms of proving identity.

What I don't understand is how it makes the user's requests and the site's responses unreadable. The site's public key is, well, public -- so can't anyone record the network traffic, capture the responses, and decode them using the public key available to everyone? They wouldn't be able to execute a man in the middle attack without the private key, but why can't they read the responses the user is getting?

And vice versa: the user presumably sends *their* public key to the server upon the initial connection, so can't someone recording the user's network traffic decrypt all the requests?

I suppose what I'm asking is: how can two-way public key cryptography provide anything but proof of ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How secure is https?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410549/how-secure-is-https)

Answer (score 8):

Your analysis of how the SSL connection is established is missing an important part of the initialization, the **key exchange**.

As part of the setup of the SSL connection, the client and server agree on a *symmetric* cipher to be used, and the key to be used with that cipher. The security is based on the strength of the cipher, and the secrecy of the symmetric key, which is known only to the client and the server.

---

The mechanics of generating and sharing the symmetric key is complicated.

In an oversimplified scenario (sufficient to answer the question that was asked) we can consider that the client generates the symmetric key to be used. The client sends the key to the server, the trick is that it sends it in a message that is encrypted with an asymmetric cipher, using the public key of the server.

Since the message (containing the "secret" key) is encrypted using the public key of the server, only the server can decrypt the message, the symmetric key is "secret" in that only the server and the client know the symmetric key.

Once the client and server have established the symmetric cipher and key to be used for encryption, the rest of the session uses that cipher and key to encrypt and decrypt messages.

---

**Q:** Can't anyone decrypt the responses?

It would be possible for any message that is "encrypted" with the server's private key to be decrypted by anyone that has the server's public key. This is however not how SSL works - messages should never be encrypted with a private key.

The "trick" (if you will) is that second key and cipher. The client generates a second "secret" key, known only to itself, and then securely sends that second key to the server. (It does this securely by encrypting the second "secret" key in a message, using the public key of the server. Either that or the client and server establish a secret key by performing a *key agreement protocol* called Diffie-Hellman to generate the secret key.

After the key establishment, the remainder of the session uses the second "secret" key, which is now known   by both the client (that generated the key), and the server.

---

As @MarteenBodewes points out, the mechanism that the client and server use for agreeing on a symmetric key, including validating the authenticity of the server, et al. is more complicated that the overly simplified explanation I gave in the answer above. That is to say, it's not correct to say that the client generates the symmetric key and sends it to the server.

No matter the actual mechanics and how complicated the key exchange is, the main idea is that the client and server *agree* on symmetric cipher to use, and agree on a secret *key* to use. The security comes from the strength of the symmetric cipher and on the secrecy of the key.

Comment: OK, now the bottom part contains key agreement and the top part doesn't :) Note that direct RSA encryption is likely to be removed from the next version of TLS.

Comment: @owlstead: I appreciate your effort in improving this answer. The "key" idea to get across is that an SSL/TLS session uses a **symmetric** cipher for the record protocol. The client and server use the **same** key for both encrypting and decrypting messages. The private key/public key asymmetric encryption is only used during the "handshake" protocol, the initial setup of the connection, and part of that setup is the client and server agreeing on the symmetric cipher and the key to be used for the record protocol.

Comment: Of course, of course, but I meant [this](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg12266.html), which means RSA encryption won't be used *at all* not even for key agreement, only RSA signatures for authentication.

Comment: @owlstead: I appreciate your comment. The SSL/TLS "record protocol" is pretty straightforward, symmetric cipher with a shared key known only by the two participants. (The security depends on the key being  kept "secret" and the strength of the cipher.) I don't think that part is  changing in the next version (But I could be entirely mistaken about that.) It's the "handshake protocol", the more complicated part of setting up the connection, that makes use of asymmetric encryption.

Comment: True, but if it uses (only) DH/ECDH then your second section will be incorrect; the keys would be created using the output of DH/ECDH - it won't be the client that generates the session keys. That's the point I'm trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

Public-private key systems are **asymmetric** (one way). Data encrypted by the public key is decrypted by the private key. Knowledge of a public key only gives you ability to encrypt a message for an intended recipient.

The server public key is only used to encrypt your initial request, which can only be decrypted by the server. Using the more traditional names Bob, Alice and Eve, Bob is our server, Alice is the client web browser, and Eve is the man in the middle. Depending on how the key exchange is implemented, Bob and Alice could each send each other a secret message, encrypted with the other's public key, without Eve being able to decrypt it, even though she knows both the parties' public keys. The public keys are of no use to decrypt those messages. Eve would need to know the private keys. Even though Eve knows the public key, and could encrypt her own message for Bob, she cannot decipher other messages created from the same public key by Alice.

If only Bob has a public-private asymmetric key, Alice can still negotiate a secure conversation with Bob using Bob's public key, and a symmetric key of her choosing. This is similar to SSL's current key exchange.

SSL (TLS) security specifies its own protocol for key exchange using RSA. RSA key exchange only requires one party (Bob / the server) to have a public-private keypair. The initial message is sent from client to server, encrypted by the server public key. The response is encrypted for the client with a key derived from the key the client initially sent, allowing a secure handshake to take place that finalizes with both sides knowing one or more session keys. Once the keys are exchanged, the bulk data is encrypted with session key(s) which are symmetric stream ciphers (RC5, DES, Blowfish, AES)

A short (oversimplified) secure exchange:

1. Client creates a secret key and encrypts it with server's public key
2. Only the server can decrypt the secret key from the client
3. Server uses client's secret key to encrypt a message and send back to client
4. Only the client can read the server response

Now the actual TLS/SSL negotiation is more complicated. But this is the general idea. You can see it described in detail here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: That vice versa part at least is wrong. You point to DH, but you don't really show how it is used. Note that RSA encryption may  disappear from TLS for 1.3, in favor of DHE. You don't explicitly specify the SSL layer at first. Otherwise the description seems OK for a relatively complicated protocol.

Comment: By vice-versa I meant to say that the server could send the client a message as well, encrypted with the client's public key. I was implying that both parties can have a public and private key and trying to emphasize the asymmetric aspect of it. I referenced DH because it is a well-known exchange. But I see your point, my explanation is a bit mixed, and the OP was specifically discussing HTTPS so possibly the link to SSL/TLS would have been more appropriate.

Comment: You are right with regards to client authentication, but I would leave client authentication out of it; it's an advanced topic and does not have too much to do with the question.

Comment: @owlstead - Agree. I removed client authentication as well as Diffie-Hellman altogether and focused on SSL RSA style exchange, per the question. Let me know if you see any other issues.

Comment: OK, but direct RSA encryption of the secret key is probably going to be removed from the next version of TLS. RSA is then only used for authentication of the server and the DH key agreement.